# Does a non-voting RPC node require a keypair?

Tags: rpc, validator

Double checking my RPC node vs voting validator node knowledge:
a non-voting RPC node does NOT require any keypairs at all? Only voting validator nodes do (of which they require 3)?
Or does a non-voting node still require an identity key?

Answer (score 4):

All nodes require at least an identity keypair to participate in gossip